# Variable undeclared error when used inside a function

Tags: c, macros

Variable 'a' doesn't resolve by pre processor macro when function fun() is defined above main() but working fine when defined below main().

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun()
{
    printf("%d",a);
}

int main()
{
    #define a 5
    fun();
    return 0 ;
}
```

What is the reason behind it? And how can we make it work so that I don't have to move the function fun() definition.

Comment: The compiler reads top to bottom so, in rough terms, needs to see the definition of `a` before it is used.    Move the`#define a 5` to before `fun()`.

Comment: `a` is not a variable. Please read how the pre-processor works and what `#define` does.

Comment: And even if `a` was a variable, please read about scope of variables. Whatever you define in `main` is not visible in `fun`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C preprocessor runs *top-down* and replaces the `#define`s ("text replacement"). So, when `#define a 5` in `main()`, it can't "go back" and replace `a` in `func()`; it can only replace the `a`'s, if any, below its `#define`.

You just need to define it above `func()`.

From [C11 draft, 6.10.3 Macro replacement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p9):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # define identifier replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines an object-like macro that **causes each subsequent instance of
>   the macro name** <sup>171</sup>) to be replaced by the replacement
>   list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the
>   directive. The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names
>   as specified below.

This has been the same since pre standard C. From [Dennis Ritchie's C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf):

> 12.1 Token replacement A compiler-control line of the form
>
> # define identifier token-string
>
> (note: no trailing semicolon) **causes the preprocessor to replace
>   subsequent instances of the identifier with the given string of tokens**
>   (except within compiler control lines). The replacement token-string
>   has comments removed from it, and it is surrounded with blanks. No
>   rescanning of the replacement string is attempted.

(*emphasis mine*).

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can't reference a preprocessor macro before defining it, that's simply not how it works.

There's no "variable" here though, your usage of the word is very confusing. The preprocessor is simply doing text replacement, the compiler will never see the `a` symbol, it will see the `5` instead (if the macro was defined).

I don't know a way to "make it work" since the goal is very strange. If you want to access a global variable, use one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int x)
{
    extern int a;
    return a + x;
}

int a = 12;

int main(void) {
    printf("a=%d, fun() returned %d\n", a, fun(11));
    return 0;
}
```

Here `extern` makes us get away with defining `a` after `fun()`, but it can't be inside `main()`.

Comment: Ooof.  That's potentially some perversely confusing code.  Not sure if I should congratulate you on coming up with that evil code or not.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Is it? Perhaps ... not very common pattern, since it tries to meet a random requirement of not re-ordering things.

Comment: Yeah, I think that it's not only an uncommon pattern, it will confuse anyone not knowing that the `extern` keyword changes the definition into a declaration, which is probably - and unfortunately - a pretty significant number of developers.  So as a purely evil way to screw with such developers, it's brilliant.  :-D

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor will replace any instances of `a` with 5 after the point of macro definition. You could place the #define line above the function fun.

As a side note, `a` is not a variable, the preprocessor will just do a text replacement before it is compiled. It would change fun to

```
void fun()
{
    printf("%d", 5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessing step is done before the compiling step. Moreover, the preprocessor does not know C; for the preprocessor the source file is just text.

In your example, the symbol `a` used in function `fun()` is not declared before use, which is an error. It does not matter that somewhere further down there is a preprocessor definition for `a`. Since the definition is further down it does not apply in the body of `fun()`: always remember that for the proeprocessor the source file is just text, it has no knowledge of C. Preprocessing directives apply at the point where they appear in text, never before.